# How to Import Multi-Database MySQLdump with 'DROP TABLE IF EXISTS'?

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

I want to copy a bunch of DB's from server1 to server2 and I want to drop any DB's on server2 that conflict with the imported DB's, then import the DB's.

I'm using this to import:

```
mysql -u root -p[password] < a_bunch_of_dbs.sql
```

I used phpMyAdmin to perform several exports but they are totally unusable.

The problem is that phpMyAdmin will either put:

```
  DROP DATABASE `database1`;
```

(it results in error #1008 - Can't drop database 'database1'; database doesn't exist)

OR:

```
  CREATE DATABASE `database1`;
```

(it results in error #1007 - Can't create database 'database1'; database exists)

**But NOT**:

```
  DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS `database`;
  CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS `database1`;
```

(obviously the "IF NOT EXISTS" is redundant but I liked it there for reassurance)

So, to solve this I either need some command line options **OR** I need to find out where phpmyadmin creates the query strings and add a "IF EXISTS" to the DROP TABLE option and that would solve everything.

Any ideas?
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take advantage of [MySQL Backup and Restore tools](http://www.devart.com/dbforge/mysql/studio/mysql-backup.html) in [dbForge Studio for MySQL](http://www.devart.com/dbforge/mysql/studio/). Turn the option 'Include IF EXISTS in DROP statement' on and you will get script like this:

```
--
-- Definition for database database1
--
DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS database1;
CREATE DATABASE database1
  CHARACTER SET latin1
  COLLATE latin1_swedish_ci;

-- 
-- Set default database
--

USE database1;

--
-- Definition for table dept
--
CREATE TABLE dept (
  id INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  dept_name VARCHAR(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (id)
)
ENGINE = INNODB
AUTO_INCREMENT = 2
AVG_ROW_LENGTH = 16384
CHARACTER SET latin1
COLLATE latin1_swedish_ci;
```

Command line is supported.

Comment: Thank you. I ended up using mysqldump for the export, rather than phpMyAdmin.